# Не могу разобраться с try/except

Tags: python

Как мне сделать так что если ошибка, то выполняется `driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2019-2020/results")`, а если и тут ошибка, то выполняется `driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2020/results")`?

```
try:
    driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2020-2021/results")
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
except Exception as ex:
    driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2019-2020/results")
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
except Exception as ex:
    driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2020/results")
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно создать еще один блок try/except:

```
try:
    driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2020-2021/results")
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
except Exception as ex:
    try:
        driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2019-2020/results")
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
    except Exception as ex:
        driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2020/results")
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
```

Если ошибка может случиться только при `get`, то можно упростить:

```
try:
    driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2020-2021/results")
except Exception as ex:
    try:
        driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2019-2020/results")
    except Exception as ex:
        driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-2020/results")
        
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно пройтись в цикле.

```
for year in ("2020-2021", "2019-2020", "2020"):
    try:
        driver.get(f"{league_hrefs}-{year}/results")
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--static.event__match--twoLine")[0].click()
        break
    except Exception as ex:
        pass
```

Comment: Тут поведения отличается чуток, от того, что в оригинальном коде. Если последний вызов бросит исключение, в оригинале оно пробрасывалось, а тут будет игнорироваться.